# Samsung netbook N150Plus screen brightness not working

Tags: 11.04, brightness, samsung

I have a Samsung netbook N150Plus (mod# NP-N150-JP02UK) on which I have just installed 11.04 but although the function key works for the screen brightness and brings up the brightness +/- animation, it does not actually change the brightness.

With power on, the screen is bright but at least I can see it (but not change it) but on battery power, the screen is so dim its almost unusable in normal daylight. I have made changes to power management to no avail. Also had the same issue when I had 10.10 installed before upgrading.

Is this a driver issue of a Linux setting problem? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

With installing the  [Voria](http://www.voria.org/forum/)-Tools we can overcome limitations of a standard Ubuntu installation on Samsung netbooks. Just [add the following ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to your sources:

```
ppa:voria/ppa
```

and install **samsung-backlight** from there. You may also find other interesting tools ther to control your Samsung netbook.

In case the functions still do not work properly I suggest you contact the [Voria team](http://www.voria.org/forum/) to help them solve the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for your time on this, I'll give it ago and see what happens. thanks again

Comment: Just updated my netbook and see now that my screen brightness issue has been addressed with a proper fix after rebooting. Thank You the guys at voria.org, it is much appreciated, believe me! Could not imagine such a fast and effective response from the 'dark side', if you know what I mean...