# Brightness Keys on Samsung X360

Tags: 12.04, brightness, samsung

I recently installed 12.04 64 on my Samsung X360 and most of the hot keys work (Volume, disable mousepad, num/scroll locks, display, battery). However, when adjusting brightness, there is only two levels - full and i guess 90%.

Any suggestions on how to increase the range of brightness levels for the hotkey?

Additionally Wifi enable/disable doesn't work either but that is less of a priority right now

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on my samsung N110 after installing 12.04, and installing samsung-tools and samsung-laptop from the voira ppa worked for me. I also had to install samsung-backlight.  See this similar question for details: [Samsung netbook N150Plus screen brightness not working](https://askubuntu.com/q/38845/61171)