# Brightness Control In Samsung RV 509

Tags: nvidia, brightness, gpu

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung laptop RV509 with Nvidia grahics card but brightness remain unchanged. How can I make the brightness control work?

Comment: The answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/38845/samsung-netbook-n150plus-screen-brightness-not-working may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using xbacklight

Install it from terminal `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`

Change brightness by xba`cklight -set <level>`, where `<level>` is an integer ranging from 0 to 100 (lowest brightness to highest).

For example, to set medium brightness one would use

```
xbacklight -set 60
```